# why "$(opener.document).ready()" is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried something like, below in popup-window, but not working...

any correction at line 3, please suggest.

```
function closePopup() {
    window.opener.history.go(0);
    $(opener.document).ready(function(){
        window.opener.some_function(some_variable);
        self.close();
    });
}
```

Comment: Um, Sorry If I am wrong, but How a child can know when parent was born?

Comment: @S.Mark not born, its about reborn.if there is a way to access parent function, then why not its onload event.I am also not sure about it. Thats why i posted here...

Comment: :D I see, but still, if parent is reborn, child will disappear also, isn't it? when I googled `"$(opener.document).ready"`, seems you are the first one who try that in the WORLD. no offense, there is lots of jQuery geeks here. lets wait other people answers.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. You can access `Window#document` of another window only if it is of the same origin (same host, port and protocol).
2. Even if the above case is satisfied, the `document` object isn't constructed immediately after you navigate to a page. `history.go()` is not a synchronous operation.

Have you tried `Window#load` event instead?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I need load event for parent window, (using "opener") usable in its popup window. I think "window.load" will work for current window.

Comment: I meant `opener.load`. opener is a `Window` too. Maybe I should capitalize Window.

Comment: i tried, and failed.Now i am using a delay bluntly in popup to wait until parent reloads.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this option: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/popupready